# Unable to install android studio ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, android-studio

From terminal unable to locate package error.
I have already added repository.

Comment: Which repository? Have you tried [Ubuntu Make](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make)?

Comment: sudo apt-add-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio

Comment: You cannot use that repo because it's only for Ubuntu 16.10 and older.

Comment: what should i do now?

Comment: also downloading the android studio and executing the .sh file it stucks at downloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to [Download Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) and download the zip file, extract the files.

[image: extract files]

Then run the following commands in your terminal

```
$ cd android-studio-ide-171.4443003-linux
```

Move the `android-studio` folder to `/opt` folder.

```
$ sudo move android-studio /opt
```

If you are running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, you need to install some 32-bit libraries with the following command

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386
```

Then cd into `bin`

```
cd ~/opt/android-studio/bin
./studio.sh # this will launch android studio
```

After launching android studio create a desktop entry by clicking `Tool > Create Desktop Entry`

[image]

When you launch android studio for the first time, it will download some components.
[image]

Comment: its constant showing 

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip

in downloading components

Comment: did you use the official download page?

Comment: yes i used official downlaod page

Comment: still showing me 
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip
even after moving it to /opt
No progress in download

Comment: It's going to download some files before it can start.

Comment: but its not progressing?

Comment: ok ill wait its 339MB

Comment: did you launch android studio with `./studio.sh`?

Comment: its progressing ... Just the matter of patience . Thank You. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your repository `ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio` does not contain packages for Ubuntu 17.10 Artful.

Remove it with `sudo ppa-purge ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio` and/or `sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio`

then add other PPA ([Ubuntu Make](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make)) and install package from it

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lyzardking/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
umake android
```

the last command will install Android Studio to your home folder with corresponding shortcuts.

Comment: should i remove all the PPA packages? I am new to ubuntu

Comment: Just execute commands from my answer - the remove only PPA which you mentioned.

Comment: its showing me this error now 
ERROR: The checksum of https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/3.0.1.0/android-studio-ide-171.4443003-linux.zip doesn't match. Corrupted download? Aborting.

Comment: I got the same `Corrupted download? Aborting` error.